# How to Toggle Visibility Between a Button and a Stack Panel Containing Two Buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, windows-community-toolkit

I am having difficulty figuring out how to toggle the visibility between three buttons. Here is the scenario:

- I have 3 buttons on a user control, an `Edit` button, an `OK` button, and a `Cancel` button.
- The `Ok` and `Cancel` buttons are grouped together in a stack panel.
- The `Edit` button is by itself.
- I would like when the `Edit` button is pressed, that it (the `Edit` button) is hidden and the stack panel containing the `Ok` and `Cancel` buttons are shown.
- When either the `Cancel` or `Ok` buttons are pressed, they are hidden, and the `Edit` button is shown again.
- There will be 7 lines on this form that are all very similar, with a label, text box, and an edit button.
- Is it possible to use only a few methods to control the visibility of all of the buttons/ stack panels.
- i.e. Can I have one Edit method and show the stack panel depending on the text box control name/ binding, instead of having to right 7 methods for showing the stack panel, 7 Ok methods and 7 cancel methods?

Here is the line on the form with the `Edit` button:

[image: Edit Button]

And here is the line on the form with the `Ok` and `Cancel` buttons:

[image: Ok and Cancel Buttons]

Here is the XAML code that I've come up with for this line:

```
<StackPanel
        Orientation="Horizontal"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Grid.Row="2"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
    <Label
        Style="{StaticResource DeviceInfoPropertyLabelStyle}">
        CONTROLLER NAME:
    </Label>
    <TextBox
        Text="{Binding ControllerName}"
        Style="{StaticResource DeviceInfoTextBoxStyle}" />
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            Grid.Column="0">

            <Button
                Command="{Binding EditCommand}"
                Visibility="{Binding IsEditButtonVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Collapsed}"
                Style="{StaticResource DeviceInfoEditButtonStyle}">
                Edit
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel
            x:Name="EditControllerNameStackPanel"
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Visibility="{Binding IsOkCancelButtonVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Visible}">
            <Button
                Command="{Binding OkEditCommand}"
                Style="{StaticResource DeviceInfoEditOkButtonStyle}">
                OK
            </Button>
            <Button
                Command="{Binding  CancelEditCommand}"
                Style="{StaticResource DeviceInfoEditCancelButtonStyle}">
                CANCEL
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Here is the code in the ViewModel that I have so far. It's only a skeleton at this point:

```
public bool IsEditButtonVisible
{
    get
    {
        bool output = false;
        if (true)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return output;
    }
}

public bool IsOkCancelButtonVisible
{
    get => true;
}


[RelayCommand]
private void Edit()
{
    if (true)
    {

    } 
}

[RelayCommand]
private void OkEdit()
{

}

[RelayCommand]
private void CancelEdit()
{

}
```

Note that I am using the MVVM Community Toolkit.

Let me know if I need to provide any additional information.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use just one boolean to toggle the visibility. Change BoolToVisibilityConverter code a bit..

```
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool b)
        {
            if (parameter is string str && str == "Inverse")
                return b ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
            return b ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
        }

        return Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Edit button

```
<Button
    Visibility="{Binding IsEditButtonVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
```

OK/Cancel stackpanel

```
<StackPanel
    Visibility="{Binding IsEditButtonVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=Inverse}">
```

ViewModel (sorry I don't use MVVM Community Toolkit)

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    
    private bool _isEditButtonVisible;

    public bool IsEditButtonVisible
    {
        set
        {
            _isEditButtonVisible = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsEditButtonVisible));
        }
        get => _isEditButtonVisible;
    }
    
    private void Edit()
    {
        IsEditButtonVisible = false;
    }

    private void Ok()
    {
        IsEditButtonVisible = true;
    }

    private void Cancel()
    {
        IsEditButtonVisible = true;
    }
    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    
    
    // other code
}
```

To apply the same logic over the other 7 similar groups, you must have at least 7 booleans, but you can have 3 commands only, where you can pass the name of the group to the command, and the command will toggle the appropriate group based on the passed parameter

In View

```
<Button
    Command="{Binding OkCommand}"
    CommandParameter="group1">
    OK
</Button>
```

In ViewModel

```
private void Edit(string commandParameter)
{
    IsEdit1ButtonVisible = commandParameter != "group1";
    IsEdit2ButtonVisible = commandParameter != "group2";
    IsEdit3ButtonVisible = commandParameter != "group3";
    // etc...
}

private void Ok(string commandParameter)
{
    IsEdit1ButtonVisible = commandParameter == "group1";
    IsEdit2ButtonVisible = commandParameter == "group2";
    IsEdit3ButtonVisible = commandParameter == "group3";
    // etc...
}

private void Cancel(string commandParameter)
{
    IsEdit1ButtonVisible = commandParameter == "group1";
    IsEdit2ButtonVisible = commandParameter == "group2";
    IsEdit3ButtonVisible = commandParameter == "group3";
    // etc...
}
```