# How to Populate a User Control with a Reusable User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, windows-community-toolkit

I asked this question ([How to Toggle Visibility Between a Button and a Stack Panel Containing Two Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73900219/how-to-toggle-visibility-between-a-button-and-a-stack-panel-containing-two-butto/73900655#73900655)) last week, and the answer was perfect and exactly what I was looking for. I realized though that I'm going to have 3 User Controls all with the very similar elements on them, so it would be better to split the row out to be re-usable. But, I am having a really hard time getting the controls to display on the form.

Here is the end result that I am looking for:
[image]

I have created this User Control, DeviceInfoRow.xaml:
[image]

And here is the XAML:

```
<UserControl 
    x:Class="StagingApp.Main.Controls.Common.DeviceInfoRow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:common="clr-namespace:StagingApp.Presentation.ViewModels.Common;assembly=StagingApp.Presentation"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=common:DeviceInfoRowViewModel}"
    mc:Ignorable="d" >

    <StackPanel
        Style="{StaticResource InfoRowStackPanelStyle}">

        <Label
            Style="{StaticResource DeviceInfoPropertyLabelStyle}"
            x:Name="InfoLabel" />
        <TextBox
            Style="{StaticResource DeviceInfoTextBoxStyle}"
            x:Name="InfoTextBox" />
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                Grid.Column="0">
                <Button
                    Command="{Binding EditCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                    Visibility="{Binding IsEditButtonVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}"
                    Style="{StaticResource DeviceInfoEditButtonStyle}">
                    Edit
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Visibility="{Binding IsEditButtonVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}, ConverterParameter=Inverse}">
                <Button
                    Command="{Binding OkCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                    Style="{StaticResource DeviceInfoEditOkButtonStyle}">
                    OK
                </Button>
                <Button
                    Command="{Binding CancelCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                    Style="{StaticResource DeviceInfoEditCancelButtonStyle}">
                    CANCEL
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

    </StackPanel>

</UserControl>
```

Here is the ViewModel for the User Control:

```
namespace StagingApp.Presentation.ViewModels.Common;
public partial class DeviceInfoRowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string? _labelText;

    public string? LabelText
    {
        get => _labelText;
        set 
        { 
            _labelText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LabelText));
        }
    }

    private string? _infoTextBox;

    public string? InfoTextBox
    {
        get => _infoTextBox;
        set 
        { 
            _infoTextBox = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(InfoTextBox));
        }
    }

    private bool _isEditButtonVisible;

    public bool IsEditButtonVisible
    {
        get => _isEditButtonVisible;
        set 
        {
            _isEditButtonVisible = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsEditButtonVisible));
        }
    }



    [RelayCommand]
    public virtual void Ok()
    {
        IsEditButtonVisible = false;
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    public virtual void Cancel()
    {
        IsEditButtonVisible = true;
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    public virtual void Edit()
    {
        IsEditButtonVisible = true;
    }
}
```

The `BaseViewModel` just implements `ObservableObject` and inherits from `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

This is what I have so far for the KitchenInfoView, which will actually display my rows:

```
<UserControl 
    x:Class="StagingApp.Main.Controls.InfoViews.KitchenInfoView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:StagingApp.Presentation.ViewModels.InfoViewModels;assembly=StagingApp.Presentation"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewmodels:KitchenInfoViewModel}"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StagingApp.Main.Controls.Common"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="725" 
    d:DesignWidth="780"
    Background="{StaticResource Blue}">
    <Grid Margin="20">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Title -->
        <Label 
            x:Name="ValidationTitle"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
            Style="{StaticResource DeviceInfoTitleStyle}">
            DEVICE VALIDATION
        </Label>

        <!-- Directions -->
        <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                Style="{StaticResource TextDirectionStyle}">
                    Please confirm that the following information is correct. 
                    If any setting is incorrect, change the value in the text box and select "Edit". 
                    The value will then be adjusted. Once all values are correct, press 'OK'.
                    The device will then reboot.
        </TextBlock>

        <!-- Data -->
        <StackPanel>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:DeviceInfoRow />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>

        <!-- Buttons -->
        <StackPanel
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Margin="0 20 0 0"
            Grid.Row="9"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2">

            <Button
                x:Name="OK"
                IsDefault="True"
                Style="{StaticResource DeviceInfoOkButtonStyle}">
                OK
            </Button>
            <Button
                x:Name="Cancel"
                IsCancel="True"
                Style="{StaticResource DeviceInfoCancelButtonStyle}">
                CANCEL
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Finally, the KitchenInfoViewModel, looks like this at the moment:

```
public partial class KitchenInfoViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    [Description("Controller Name")]
    private string? _controllerName;

    [ObservableProperty]
    [Description("Controller Number")]
    private string? _controllerNumber;

    [ObservableProperty]
    [Description("BOH Server Name")]
    private string? _bohServerName;

    [ObservableProperty]
    [Description("TERMSTR")]
    private string? _termStr;

    [ObservableProperty]
    [Description("Key Number")]
    private string? _keyNumber;

    [ObservableProperty]
    [Description("IP Address")]
    private string? _ipAddress;

    [ObservableProperty]
    [Description("BOH IP Address")]
    private string? _bohIpAddress;

    private ObservableCollection<DeviceInfoRowViewModel> _rows;

    public ObservableCollection<DeviceInfoRowViewModel> Rows
    {
        get => _rows;
        set
        {
            _rows = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    public KitchenInfoViewModel()
    {
        _rows = new ObservableCollection<DeviceInfoRowViewModel>();
        var properties = typeof(KitchenInfoViewModel)
            .GetProperties();


        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var attribute = property.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DescriptionAttribute));
            var description = (DescriptionAttribute)attribute;
            _rows.Add(new DeviceInfoRowViewModel()
            {
                LabelText = description?.Description.ToString(),
                InfoTextBox = ""
            });
        }
    }

}
```

My goal is to be able to use the DeviceInfoRow over and over again on various forms, with the content of the label coming from the description of the string properties in the VM. The text box should bind to each property.

Is this possible? Am I asking too much? Am I close? I've been banging my head against a wall all day on this.

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT:

To explain what I'm trying to do a little bit better:

This is a single window application. Depending on the type of device that this application will be deployed on will determine which initial view the ShellView will load. There are three different configurations: Server, Kitchen, Terminal. But each configuration is very similar:

**Kitchen Configure View**
[image: Kitchen Configure View]

**Server Configure View**
[image: Server Configure View]

**Terminal Configure View**
[image: Terminal Configure View]

As you can see, each of the three views are very similar, even capturing the similar information. What is meant to happen is that after the user inputs the information into the form, they will select "Configure" and the device will automatically be configured, using the information provided. That information will be stored in a separate model to be used by the information.

Once the device is finished being configured, the Device Validation form (a modal form) will pop up, alerting the user that the configuration is finished and to double check that the device was configured correctly (because these are Windows devices and sometimes things don't work the way they should). Initially all of the information on the Device Validation form was static, but I had the idea to populate a text box with the device information (coming from the device). This way, if something is incorrect, the user can press "Edit", enter the correct information in the text box and then press "OK". The application at that point will make the necessary changes to the device, and then re-display the form.

Again each form has a very similar look to it, with a label (or text block), text box, and a couple of buttons for each row. The Configure forms also are very similar, with a label and text box. What I'm looking for is instead of copying and pasting each row in the XAML file, having a template row (one for Validation, one for Configure) that can then be populated with the Description attribute of the properties (for the Label portion) and bound to the individual properties (for the TextBox portion).

I really hope this clears things up and makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Harlan, I want to show you an implementation that you might be able to use for your question.

```cs
using System.Windows;

namespace Core2022.SO.Harlan.DescriptionShow
{
    public class DescriptionDto
    {
        public string Description { get; }

        public PropertyPath Path { get; }

        public bool IsReadOnly { get; }
        public object? Source { get; }

        public DescriptionDto(string description, PropertyPath path, bool isReadOnly, object? source)
        {
            Description = description ?? string.Empty;
            Path = path;
            IsReadOnly = isReadOnly;
            Source = source;
        }

        public DescriptionDto SetSource(object? newSource)
            => new DescriptionDto(Description, Path, IsReadOnly, newSource);

        public override string ToString() => Description;
    }
}
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;

namespace Core2022.SO.Harlan.DescriptionShow
{
    public class DescriptionPropertyList
    {
        public object Source { get; }

        public ReadOnlyCollection<DescriptionDto> Descriptions { get; }

        public DescriptionPropertyList(object source)
        {
            Source = source ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

            Type sourceType = source.GetType();
            if (!typeDescriptions.TryGetValue(sourceType, out ReadOnlyCollection<DescriptionDto>? descriptions))
            {
                PropertyInfo[] properties = sourceType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
                DescriptionDto[] descrType = new DescriptionDto[properties.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
                {
                    PropertyInfo property = properties[i];
                    string descr = property.GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>()?.Description ??
                                    property.Name;
                    descrType[i] = new DescriptionDto(descr, new PropertyPath(property), !property.CanWrite, Empty);
                }
                descriptions = Array.AsReadOnly(descrType);
                typeDescriptions.Add(sourceType, descriptions);
            }

            DescriptionDto[] descrArr = new DescriptionDto[descriptions.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < descriptions.Count; i++)
            {
                descrArr[i] = descriptions[i].SetSource(source);
            }
            Descriptions = Array.AsReadOnly(descrArr);
        }

        private static readonly object Empty = new object();
        private static readonly Dictionary<Type, ReadOnlyCollection<DescriptionDto>> typeDescriptions
            = new Dictionary<Type, ReadOnlyCollection<DescriptionDto>>();
    }
}
```

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Core2022.SO.Harlan.DescriptionShow
{
    public class ExampleClass
    {
        [Description("Controller Name")]
        public string? ControllerName { get; set; }

        [Description("Controller Number")]
        public string? ControllerNumber { get; set; }

        [Description("BOH Server Name")]
        public string? BohServerName { get; set; }

        [Description("TERMSTR")]
        public string? TermStr { get; set; }

        [Description("Key Number")]
        public string? KeyNumber { get; set; }

        [Description("IP Address")]
        public string? IpAddress { get; set; }

        [Description("BOH IP Address")]
        public string? BohIpAddress { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace Core2022.SO.Harlan.DescriptionShow
{
    [TemplatePart(Name = TextBoxTemplateName, Type = typeof(TextBox))]
    public class DescriptionControl : Control
    {
        private const string TextBoxTemplateName = "PART_TextBox";
        private TextBox? PartTextBox;
        private Binding? TextBinding;
        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            PartTextBox = GetTemplateChild(TextBoxTemplateName) as TextBox;
            if (PartTextBox is TextBox tbox)
            {
                if (TextBinding is Binding binding)
                {
                    tbox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
                }
                else
                {
                    BindingOperations.ClearBinding(tbox, TextBox.TextProperty);
                }
            }
        }

        static DescriptionControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DescriptionControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(DescriptionControl)));
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Data source, path and description of its property.
        /// </summary>
        public DescriptionDto DescriptionSource
        {
            get => (DescriptionDto)GetValue(DescriptionSourceProperty);
            set => SetValue(DescriptionSourceProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary><see cref="DependencyProperty"/> для свойства <see cref="DescriptionSource"/>.</summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DescriptionSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                nameof(DescriptionSource),
                typeof(DescriptionDto),
                typeof(DescriptionControl),
                new PropertyMetadata(null, DescriptionSourceChangedCallback));

        private static void DescriptionSourceChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DescriptionControl descriptionControl = (DescriptionControl)d;
            Binding? binding = null;
            if (e.NewValue is DescriptionDto description)
            {
                binding = new Binding();
                binding.Path = description.Path;
                binding.Source = description.Source;
                if (description.IsReadOnly)
                {
                    binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
                }
                else
                {
                    binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
                }
            }
            descriptionControl.TextBinding = binding;
            if (descriptionControl.PartTextBox is TextBox tbox)
            {
                if (binding is null)
                {
                    BindingOperations.ClearBinding(tbox, TextBox.TextProperty);
                }
                else
                {
                    tbox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Default Template in Themes/Generic.xaml file:

```xml
    <Style xmlns:dsc="clr-namespace:Core2022.SO.Harlan.DescriptionShow"
           TargetType="{x:Type dsc:DescriptionControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type dsc:DescriptionControl}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <UniformGrid Rows="1">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DescriptionSource.Description, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type dsc:DescriptionControl}}}"/>
                            <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox"/>
                        </UniformGrid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Core2022.SO.Harlan.DescriptionShow
{
    public class DescriptionsListControl : Control
    {
        static DescriptionsListControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DescriptionsListControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(DescriptionsListControl)));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Descriptions List
        /// </summary>
        public ReadOnlyCollection<DescriptionDto> Descriptions
        {
            get => (ReadOnlyCollection<DescriptionDto>)GetValue(DescriptionsProperty);
            private set => SetValue(DescriptionsPropertyKey, value);
        }

        private static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<DescriptionDto> descriptionsEmpty = Array.AsReadOnly(Array.Empty<DescriptionDto>());

        private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey DescriptionsPropertyKey =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(
                nameof(Descriptions),
                typeof(ReadOnlyCollection<DescriptionDto>),
                typeof(DescriptionsListControl),
                new PropertyMetadata(descriptionsEmpty));
        /// <summary><see cref="DependencyProperty"/> for property <see cref="Descriptions"/>.</summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DescriptionsProperty = DescriptionsPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

        public DescriptionsListControl()
        {
            DataContextChanged += OnDataContextChanged;
        }

        private DescriptionPropertyList? descriptionPropertyList;
        private void OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NewValue is null)
            {
                descriptionPropertyList = null;
                Descriptions = descriptionsEmpty;
            }
            else
            {
                descriptionPropertyList = new DescriptionPropertyList(e.NewValue);
            }
            Descriptions = descriptionPropertyList?.Descriptions ?? descriptionsEmpty;
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<Window x:Class="Core2022.SO.Harlan.DescriptionShow.DescriptionsExampleWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2022.SO.Harlan.DescriptionShow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="DescriptionsExampleWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CompositeCollection x:Key="items">
            <local:ExampleClass ControllerName="First"/>
            <local:ExampleClass ControllerName="Second"/>
            <local:ExampleClass ControllerName="Third"/>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </Window.Resources>
    <UniformGrid Columns="2">
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{DynamicResource items}"
                 DisplayMemberPath="ControllerName"
                 SelectedIndex="0"/>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=listBox}">
            <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:DescriptionsListControl>
                        <Control.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:DescriptionsListControl}">
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Descriptions}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DescriptionDto}">
                                            <local:DescriptionControl DescriptionSource="{Binding}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Control.Template>
                    </local:DescriptionsListControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        </ContentControl>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>
```

If you are interested in such an implementation, then ask questions - I will try to answer them.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at this and let you know.

Comment: I like this approach. It seems like it would remove a lot of code repetition. I'm trying to figure out how to remove the list box portion, and just have the label (or text block) and text box bound to the property. That way when the text boxes are populated later, it should be easier to update them.

Comment: I didn't quite understand you (I don't have a good knowledge of English). Explain in more detail. The list of properties is obtained in the constructor of the DescriptionPropertyList class. You can add some filters to the logic to display not all properties.
Also in the DescriptionControl logic for properties that have a setter, a bidirectional binding is created. If you enter values in the TextBox, they are stored in the properties of the source.  For properties without a setter, a one-way binding is created. The values of these TextBoxes can be read from the button command.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble figuring out how best to implement this in my application. The application is a single window application. Upon launch it will check for certain criteria and display a different screen based on this. As such, I am only using one window (ShellView.xaml), and all subsequent screens will be user controls. I am also using MVVM, if that makes any difference.  (cont. in next comment)

Comment: Because many of the screens will have very similar looks to them, my initial thought was to create a reusable User Control (one row with Label, TextBox, and Button) and then populate another User Control with multiples of the row depending on the properties needed and information collected. At this point, I think I'm having trouble binding the reusable row to the ViewModel. Does that make sense? Would it make sense to take this discussion offline?

Comment: From what I understand, you need to add the implementation of DescriptionDto and DescriptionControl.
I do not fully understand what kind of logic you want to get from the Row View (DescriptionControl). TextBlock - description, TextBox - is binding to a property. Is TwoWay binding necessary? Button - what should happen on click?

Comment: @Harlan, Maybe you need this logic: TextBox with OneWay binding. When the button is clicked, the source (DescriptionDto.Source), the path to the property (DescriptionDto.Path) and the new value for this property received from the TextBox are passed to the command parameter.
You will bind the command to the ViewModel. And this information will be enough for editing.

Comment: In such a task, there is a nuance with the correctness of the TextBox value. It returns a value of type String, and the source property can be of any type. Do I need to inline the binding to cast the value of the TextBox to the type of the source property?

Comment: It would be more convenient if you described in more detail in your question the required logic from the row view element, and how you intend to use it later. For example, the issue of getting a list of string sources is not entirely clear. Initially, I understood that you need strings for ALL of the source property. But now, I'm not sure about that anymore. Maybe you only need properties that have a Descriptor? Or do you need to get properties from some kind of lists? Perhaps something else.

Comment: I've edited the question. I hope this helps. I guess I'm just having a hard time implementing these Custom Controls in my application. I think I understand how they work on a basic level, but can't figure out how to get them to work with what I am trying to do.

Comment: Doesn't the implementation I suggested create the views you need?

Comment: So I think I understand how to implement the custom controls. Using your implementation, I create a DesriptionControl.xaml in Themes. I can then create a DescriptionConfigureRow.xaml and DescriptionInfoRow.xaml in the same folder. Then I would also need to create a DescriptionConfigureRow.cs and DescriptionInfoRow.cs, both of which would implement from DescriptionControl. Then I would be able to use the DescriptionConfigureRow or the DescriptionInfoRow in one of my views. I think my biggest question is what am I binding to? Is there a way that we could communicate that I could show you my code

Comment: @Harlan, The most convenient way is if you upload your solution to a repository on GitHub and provide a link to this repository.

Comment: On the subject of bindings, they are created in the Template and Code of the DescriptionControl class. The TextBlock is bound to the value of the DescriptionSource property. The TextBox is a bit trickier because the binding needs to be recreated when the source and property path change. Therefore, a mandatory element with the name "PART_TextBox" is searched in the Template (this is reported by the class  "TemplatePart" attribute) and a new binding is programmatically created for this element whenever the DescriptionSource property is changed.

Comment: Here is the GitHub link: https://github.com/hmsiegel/StagingApp

Comment: @Harlan , I don't understand the following nuances: 1) Part of the fields is a TextBox, and part is a ComboBox. By what criterion to understand how the property should be presented? And where to get the source of elements for the ComboBox? 2) Should value changes in the GUI be propagated immediately to the source properties? Or changes are made only on the "OK" command?

Comment: 1) If I understand you correctly, you want to know which properties to display. Any properties that have a description attribute. On the two of the Configure pages, there are only three rows, with some of them using ComboBoxes. The sources from the ComboBoxes are coming from a list in the VM that I populate from an enum. I wouldn't worry about the ComboBoxes. 2) Changes are made only after the user selects "OK" or "Configure". This is not a very interactive application. I hope that helps.

Comment: @Harlan, Yes, it's clearer.
I have looked at your solution. There needs to be a lot of edits.
If you can, please send me an invite to EldHasp https://github.com/EldHasp.
I will make changes and commit them in a separate branch.
This will make it easier to share code.

Comment: A separate difficulty is the use of ToolKit. You set the DescriptionAttribute to the fields, but you need to show properties of the same name that do not have this attribute. I made the necessary changes to the DescriptionPropertyList for this. Now I'm thinking about the best way to show you the modified code.

Comment: I'm not married to Toolkit. I did something similar to this before with Caliburn.Micro, which I am comfortable with. My thought with Toolkit was to reduce the amount of boilerplate code to write. But I think we are early enough in the process that it wouldn't be too hard to change if you think it would be easier.

Comment: @Harlan , I posted the first part of the changes. As soon as I have free time, I will post the following changes.

Comment: @Harlan , If you have tested the first part of the changes, then write what should be considered in further changes so that it is useful for your task.

Comment: I have looked at the changes. So far, they look good. One issue that I've run into is the spacing between DescriptionControls when implemented on the KitchenInfoView or KitchenConfigureView. I'm also thinking about my use of Toolkit. I wanted to reduce the amount of boilerplate code, but I don't think Toolkit gives me the implementations that I need. I may switch back to Caliburn.Micro. Finally, I'm looking at how to implement the buttons that are part of the KitchenInfoView. There should be an Edit button, which when pressed will bring up an OK and CANCEL button.

Comment: @Harlan , The distances are large due to the fact that I did not set the columns in the DescriptionControl element template. Set there "<UniformGrid Columns="2" Rows="1">" (Fix I posted).
As for editing, I'm interested in such a question. Should property changes occur immediately, or should the "OK" command be passed to which properties should receive new values?

Comment: changing setting the columns and rows for the uniform grid definitely makes it better. Properties should receive the new values when the OK button is pressed. The idea is that each individual OK button (in each row) will need to be bound to a separate command, which will then call other commands depending on the property. The Edit and Cancel buttons are only used for toggling visibility. The OK button at the bottom of the InfoView will then call a separate OK command to complete the configuration.

Comment: @Harlan , Since the implementation of the control is maximally generalized, the transfer of new property values ​​to the command should also be done as generally as possible. I'm thinking about how to solve this.
Perhaps it makes sense to pass "Dictionary<string, object>" to the command, where the Key is the path to the property (in the simplest case, the name of the property), and the Value is the new value of this property. I'll try to implement something like this

Comment: The second question is how to deal with the property type. In your example, all properties are strings and you don't need to change the TextBox.Text type. But a property can be of any type. And then not every entered value in Text can be converted to a property type.

Comment: For this implementation, all of the properties will be strings. For the ConfigureViews, there are a couple of ObservableCollections (lists) but since those are hard coded values, we don't have to worry about them.

Comment: @Harlan , Look at the commit: "Implementation of editing and communication with commands in the ViewModel."

Comment: One thing that I've noticed is that you keep re-using the KitchenInfoView in the KitchenConfigureView. These are two separate views and should not be sharing controls. If you look at the initial question, the first picture is what the KitchenInfoView should look like. Below that is the InfoViewRow. When the user clicks Edit, the OK and Cancel buttons should become visible. But the OK and Cancel buttons for the entire form are separate. In my edit are the three ConfigureViews. These only contain one button at the bottom of the form, a Configure button. Nothing else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248888/discussion-between-harlan-and-eldhasp).

Answer (score 1):

> with the content of the label coming from the description of the string properties in the VM. The text box should bind to each property

You already have `DeviceInfoRowViewModel` encapsulating all the initial setup and user updates to the TextBox. I think defining all of these ObservableProperties **manually** is going againts the automation you want to achieve by using reflection in KitchenInfoViewModel constructor!

Take a look at this

```
public partial class KitchenInfoViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<DeviceInfoRowViewModel> Rows { get; set; }

    public KitchenInfoViewModel()
    {
        Rows = new ObservableCollection<DeviceInfoRowViewModel>{
            new DeviceInfoRowViewModel
            {
                LabelText = "Controller Name"
            },
            new DeviceInfoRowViewModel
            {
                LabelText = "Controller Number"
            },
            new DeviceInfoRowViewModel
            {
                LabelText = "BOH Server Name"
            },
            new DeviceInfoRowViewModel
            {
                LabelText = "TERMSTR"
            },
            new DeviceInfoRowViewModel
            {
                LabelText = "Key Number"
            },
            new DeviceInfoRowViewModel
            {
                LabelText = "IP Address"
            },
            new DeviceInfoRowViewModel
            {
                LabelText = "BOH IP Address"
            }
        };
    }
}
```

You might say

> With properties, I can use `_ipAddress` directly in code, so how can I refer to it directly now?

You might have these literals in .resx file

```
new DeviceInfoRowViewModel
{
    LabelText = Resources._ipAddress
}
```

So you whenever you want ipAddress Data, you can retrieve it from `Rows`

```
var ipAddressData = Rows.FirstOrDefault(item => item.LabelText == Resources._ipAddress);
```

You can define this as get-only property if you want to refer to it repeatedly

```
private DeviceInfoRowViewModel IpAddressData => 
     Rows.FirstOrDefault(item => item.LabelText == Resources._ipAddress);
```

My advice is to *Keep it simple*, you can do the same thing in any other View/ViewModel, your UserControl is well designed and reusable, I can't think of a way simpler and requires less-code than this (compared to the current KitchenInfoViewModel you have).

You might say:

> With ObservableProperties, I can just remove the property to remove the row from UI

You can remove its definition from `Rows` to remove the row from UI as well.

---

Back to your original question..

> Is this possible?

If you want to stick with your approach, you can do it like this

In `DeviceInfoRowViewModel`

```
public Action<string> OnInfoChanged { set; get; } // <--------------- 1

private string? _infoTextBox;

public string? InfoTextBox
{
    get => _infoTextBox;
    set 
    { 
        _infoTextBox = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(InfoTextBox));
        OnInfoChanged?.Invoke(value); // <--------------- 2
    }
}
```

In `KitchenInfoViewModel`

```
_rows.Add(new DeviceInfoRowViewModel()
{
    LabelText = description?.Description.ToString(),
    OnInfoChanged = newUsernput => property.SetValue(this, newUsernput, null); // <--------------- 3
});
```

So when user updates `InfoTextBox`, the action will assign the new value to the ObservableProperty.

Comment: The first approach seems to be closer to what I was looking for.